# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy, vector, opencv

I'm extracting features and pass them to a training classifier as a vector. I got this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`
```

I understand the error but I don't seem to know what I did wrong, any help?

```
def featurestest (img):
    # corners
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 25, 0.01, 10)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    for i in corners:
        x, y = i.ravel()
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, 255, -1)

    # edges
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 100, apertureSize=3)
    minLineLength = 50
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180, threshold=100, lines=np.array([]),
                            minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=80)

    a, b, c = lines.shape
    for i in range(a):
        cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # print(lines, edges)

    # aspect ratio
    ar = 1.0 * float(img.shape[1] / img.shape[0])

    # skew and kurtosis

    skew = scipy.stats.skew(img)
    kurt = scipy.stats.kurtosis(img)

    for i in range(0, img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, img.shape[1]):

         vector_val = np.arange([lines,edges, ar, x, y, skew,kurt])
         return_raf= (vector_val)

    return return_raf
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
vector_val = np.arange([lines, edges, ar, x, y, skew, kurt])
```

is wrong. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `np.arange` takes a start, stop, and stepsize, and returns an array of evenly-spaced numbers in that range. You're giving it a list as its first argument, which is a type error.

The actual error message comes up because `np.arange` internally is computing its range by doing something like `(stop - start) / step`. `stop` in this case is the list you give it, and `start` defaults to 0. So it's doing `[lines, edges, ar, x, y, skew, kurt] - 0`, which raises the exact `TypeError` here.

Comment: i added np.arange because it was one of the solutions to turn vector to numpy array, is there any other way?

Comment: If you want to convert that list to a vector, use `np.array`. `np.arange` is analogous to the Python builtin `range`, creating an array of linearly spaced values. It does not construct a new array from some values, like you want to do here.